# Grouping data by month in SPARQL?

Tags: date, rdf, sparql

Is it possible to extract month element from the date using SPARQL and group results by it. I am using W3 time ontology for defining dates in format `"2009-12-31"^^xsd:date`.

So in case of `"2009-12-31"^^xsd:date` I would like to extract `12`.

Is this even possible. If so, how can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SPARQL 1.1 there's a month() function (http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-month) which extracts the month from ISO dates.

you can group by month using the GROUP BY keyword, as in:

```
SELECT ?mon SUM(?val)
WHERE {
  ?x :date ?date ;
     :value ?val .
}
GROUP BY (month(?date) AS ?mon)
```

The only slight problem is that SPARQL systems aren't required to process xsd:date datatypes, just xsd:dateTime, but many will handle it correctly.

Comment: Perhaps this depends on the instance on which you execute the query (or it might have change over time), but the select part for me only worked when defined as:
`SELECT ?mon (SUM(?val) as ?sumVal) WHERE { ... `